# Permission denied when Pushing to Bitbucket after Sierra Update

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, sourcetree

I want to push some changes I made to Bitbucket. This worked well until I made the macOS Sierra update.

Now, I get the error (Pushing in SourceTree)

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists. Pushing to ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx.xx:xxx/xxx/xxxx.git
> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
> repository.

My key still exists. But the authentication is impossible.
When I enter `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.com` in the console and say 'yes', it tries three private keys and prints

> No more authentication methods to try.
>
> Permission denied (publickey)

Any idea why this has happened and how I can fix it?

**UPDATE**
Output of `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.com`:

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/corinna/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.com [104.192.143.7] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.268-723a194 app-127
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.268-723a194 app-127
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa [many cryptical characters here]
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/corinna/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/corinna/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 0):

Sierra brought some changes to the way ssh-agent works. Try adding this to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My config file looks like this, now: 
`Host bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 AddKeysToAgent yes`
But the error is still there...

Comment: I'm not sure whether it works under a `Host` section or only at the top of the file. You can test whether this is the issue by using `ssh-add` to add your bitbucket key manually, though. All this setting does is automate adding the key to the agent for you.

Comment: `$ ssh add` says 'Identity added [path]/.ssh/id_rsa'. Unfortunately, the permission is still denied. Same with position changing of `AddKeysToAgent`

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `ssh -v git@bitbucket.com` (or whatever the hostname in your remote actually is)? And also I assume you have verified the key fingerprint in your local key and the one on the bitbucket web site do match?

Comment: My local key fingerprint has 50 characters (got with `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`). The Bitbucket key is much longer...

Comment: @chocolatecake Are you sure SourceTree is using `id_rsa`? I installed it to look at the config, and it only allows me to generate a new key, not to specify an existing one. What key does SourceTree's settings say you are using?

Comment: I can't see any .pub file in Bitbucket. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133369/discussion-between-dan-lowe-and-chocolate-cake).

Comment: Sry for my absence yesterday. Some people in my proximity tried to help me. The solution was to uninstall and reinstall Sourcetree. Yay, I love solutions like this...